# Run all tests in nunit3-console with unset category

Tags: nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I am trying to run nunit3-console tests with where filter that returns true when category is not set. How do I set 'no category specified'? I have tried various forms with no luck.

```
nunit3-console MyTests.dll --where "cat == ''"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this functionality doesn't currently exist.

There's an open GitHub issue, currently considering whether to add it - you may wish to add your voice, if this is something you'd want.

https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/179

The best you can currently do is 'where cat is not' for all current categories, i.e.

```
--where "cat!=CAT1 && cat != CAT2 && cat != CAT3"
```

Comment: I was afraid it would be the case. Either way thanks for info.